# Prevent FlowLayoutPanel scrolling to updated Control

Tags: c#

I have an application which uses a FlowLayoutPanel with a lot of Custom UserControls in it. The Custom UserControls contains a Label.

The problem:
When the Label is updated the FlowLayoutPanel automatically scrolls it into view (Similar to the FlowLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView() function).

This is the code snippet that makes the FlowLayoutPanel Scroll:

```
private void DownloadChanged(Object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        progressDownload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblDownloaded.Text = e.BytesReceived.ToString() + " / " + e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString();
}
```

I have been trying to find an event in the FlowLayoutPanel which I can intercept and stop it from scrolling when a child updates but I have not had any luck so far.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how would I go about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the the Label's `AutoSize` Property to **False** seems to do the trick.

Read more here: [Similar Issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/winforms/thread/029b1590-b3f1-4443-88db-3df38ab54bd2)

Answer (score 6):

If having scrolling issues when clicking on a control in a FlowlayoutPanel, 
use an inherited control:

```
public class MyFlowLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{

    protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
    {
        //return base.ScrollToControl(activeControl);
        return this.AutoScrollPosition;
    }
}
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cb8ac2d4-5940-4ed2-9f09-22cd4b76032b/suppressing-automatic-scrolling-within-flowlayoutpanel-with-autoscroll?forum=winforms